# Connect to external Sharepoint on-premise site through Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

Is there any way to connect to an external on-premise site through Powershell?
Maybe through SP online management shell?

Answer (score 0):

The online management shell won't help you here. It will be dependent on an online tenant which yours is not one. You won't be able to use the on-prem cmdlets against an external farm.  You absolutely can use CSOM within powershell to connect to a remote on-prem server, but I think the other option that might work is PNP (which uses CSOM). Please find more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this now.

Comment: Thanks Dana, I'm trying this now.